# VBA SPLIT by different delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have a rather tricky problem. I am trying to split and declare a different parts of a string for further use. Obviously there I have a different delimiters to do that.

Say I wanted to split a standard screw code: DIN912M6x10A2 into it's different parts since each part of that code means specific something.

ScreHead is Left up to first "M" without the delimiter = DIN912

ScrewThickness is "M" included up to "x" excluded = M5

ScrewLenght is "x" excluded up to "A" excluded = 10

ScrewMaterial is "A" included up to the " " or if there's no " " then up to the end of the string = A2

What I have so far codewise is (I am working in 5th column):

```
Dim ScrewHead As Long
ScrewHead = Split(Cells(i, 5), "M"-1)

Dim ScrewDiameter As Long
ScrewDiameter =Split(i,5),"M", "x"-1)

Dim ScrewLenght As Long
ScrewLenght =Split(i,5),"x"-1, "A"-1)

Dim ScrewMaterial As Long
ScrewMaterial =Split(i,5),"A", " ")
```

Could someone help me with figuring this one out?

Comment: How did you get `M5` when the string is `M6`. Are you subtracting 1 from the result?

Comment: *Sidenote:* The captured variables are **not** to be declared as long. They are not numeric apart from "ScrewLenght".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a nice job for a regular expression to be honest when you can capture all the parts in their own groups. For example through:

```
^(.+?)(M\d+)x(\d+)(.+?)(?:\s.*)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pTO6C0/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(.+?)` - A 1st capture group holding 1+ (lazy) characters upto;
- `(M\d+)` - 2nd Capture group with a literal "M" followed by 1+ (greedy) digits.
- `x` - A literal "x".
- `(\d+)` - A 3rd capture group holding 1+ (greedy) digits.
- `(.+?)` - A 4th capture group holding 1+ (lazy) characters upto;
- `(?:\s.*)?` - An optional non-capture group of a space character with 0+ (greedy) characters.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

Here is a quick code to run to retrieve these groups:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "DIN912M6x10A2 test"
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^(.+?)(M\d+)x(\d+)(.+?)(?:\s.*)?$"
    If .Test(str) = True Then
        For Each Match In .Execute(str)(0).Submatches
            Debug.Print Match
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

---

A more extensive code-example for a better understanding:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "DIN912M6x10A2 test"
Dim ScrewHead As String, ScrewDiameter As String, ScrewLenght As Long, ScrewMaterial As String
Dim matches

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^(.+?)(M\d+)x(\d+)(.+?)(?:\s.*)?$"
    If .Test(str) = True Then
        Set matches = .Execute(str)
        ScrewHead = matches(0).Submatches(0)
        ScrewDiameter = matches(0).Submatches(1)
        ScrewLenght = matches(0).Submatches(2)
        ScrewMaterial = matches(0).Submatches(3)
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code seems very confusing to me and M5 may as well be M100. That's why I wrote down the absolute limits, because each part may vary in length. And how would I reference thos parts further on in a handy way? If I dim each part like in my original post - it's handy to reference them in a human language like If ScrewThickness.value>60 then. You know what I mean?

Comment: First of all, `M100` is not a problem to capture. Just give it a try. About your 2nd point; unfortunately there is no way we can use named capture-groups in VBA's regex object, however you can just refer to each submatch individually if you want to assign their value to a variable. For example: `Screwhead = .Execute(str)(0).Submatches(0)` and `ScrewDiameter = .Execute(str)(0).Submatches(1)`. You can also set the "match" object and refer to that without executing the pattern multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. Not quite sure why is there an IF function? As I'm not trying to find a match. I am simply trying to declare different parts of the value in 5th column and use that dim in further functions of the same sub. I.e. I need to further compare if the item I am evaluating is thicker than specified value or if screwhead is not DIN912 and so on.

Comment: It's just a build-in security because `Set matches = .Execute(str)` will return an error if there is no valid match to be found. The `.Test(str)` is there to counter that and if no match is to be found the whole assignment is skipped.

Comment: Makes sense, so in your second code, I suppose, I can reference different parts of the string as "ScrewHead" and so on. That line that says "Dim str As String: str = "DIN912M6x10A2 test"" is not necessary in actual application as far as I understand. Is that correct?

Comment: @Eduards, it's just there as a replacement for your string assignment yes. Just for showcasing.

Comment: Yup, that second code is rather understandable and does the thing necessary! Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you redefine     If Cells(i, 3).Value = "203" Then
        Set matches = .Execute(str) to say "If 3rd column value is 203 then split the value in column 5? Is it something like Then cells(i,5).execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231103/discussion-between-eduards-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain VBA based sledgehammer approach. You can adopt the code to suit your requirements.

```
Public Sub GetDiffPartsofString()
    Dim strInput As String, strScrewHead As String, strScrewThck As String, strScrewLeng As String, strScrewMatl As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    strInput = "DIN912M6x10A2"
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        Select Case Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        Case "M"
            strScrewHead = Mid(strInput, j, i - 1)
            j = i
        Case "x"
            strScrewThck = Mid(strInput, j, i - j)
            j = i
        Case "A"
            strScrewLeng = Mid(strInput, j + 1, i - j - 1)
            strScrewMatl = Mid(strInput, i, Len(strInput))
        End Select
    Next i
    Debug.Print strScrewHead, strScrewThck, strScrewLeng, strScrewMatl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still looks way too confusing and complex for the task. As what I need to do is dim different parts of the value in 5th column and use that dim in further functions of the same sub. I.e. I need to further compare if teh item I am evaluating say is thicker than specified value or if screwhead is not DIN912 and so on.

Comment: @Eduards pattern matching is in it self a rather complex task... therefore the solution will most likely be rather complex aswell

Comment: Just be aware of possible trailing spaces (and text) here.

Comment: @JvdV I tested it for a sample like `"DIN912 M6 x10 A2"` for which it works.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I meant trailing spaces as per the OP's requirements in the "ScrewMaterial" section. There can be trailing spaces right after the text that needs to be split. For example, check the input I used in my answer. Btw, it's just positive feedback not criticism =)

Comment: @JvdV, absolutely, I took this as offence :) Just kidding! I tested for a sample like `DIN912 M6 x10 A2 test test and this is one more test` for which it also seems to work as I have used length of whole string to capture the last part.

Answer (score 2):

**Tricky split approach via `Val()`**

Another *way leading to Rome*:

```
Sub AnalyzeID()
    Dim s As String: s = "DIN912M6x10A2 test"
    Dim parts: parts = Split(Replace(Replace(s, "M", "x"), " ", "x"), "x")
    'adjust split elements
    parts(1) = "M" & parts(1)
    parts(3) = Split(parts(2), Val(parts(2)))(1)  ' (don't change code line order!)
    parts(2) = Val(parts(2))
    Debug.Print Join(parts, "|")    ' ~~> DIN912|M6|10|A2
End Sub
```

**Output in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
    DIN912|M6|10|A2
```