# VBA python regular expression

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have a regular expression

```
^(.+?)M(\d+)(.+?)(?:\s.*)?$
```

Which splits occasions like "DIN934M12A2" but also occasions like "DIN934M12A2_LH"
I need to define that regular expression so that occasions like "DIN934M12A2_LH" would not comply and return an error when I run such string in VBA.

As I'm really new to regular expressions, could someone, please, help me solve this problem?

Comment: This is different to your previous pattern/question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67086413/9758194). Can you please be more precise and let us know what you need this to be split in?

Comment: Yup, previously we were looking at screws, bolts and such, but this one is a Nut. "_LH" means that it's left handed thread and I need to skip it via returning an error. I was able to modify the screw regular expression to comply with a common nut code. And the problem occured in this case. I know that if it's " LH" - space splits teh groups, but that "_" needs to be there. 

In this case DIN934 is a type M12 is inner diameter and A2 is a material. In some case I may have a _LH at the end that I need to make noncompliant to the expression.

Comment: The idea as I realized it for screws etc. is that screw code may be different, for example, there may be strength or thread step in the code and your expression from other question did return error on such occasions, which is right :)

Comment: without looking to much indepth here, the previous code I wrote under your former question should not return an error, hence the `.Test()` part. Besides, maybe you can use other string-functions to check the last three characters in this case inside an `IF()`, isntead of using regex?

Comment: You are making things too difficult for yourself.  You have two options. 1 You add a guard statement which uses instr to determine if there is a "\_" in the string and aborts before it calls your regular expression. 2 You use the split method, splitting at the '_' and if item(1) of the resulting array has a length greater than 0 you abort as above, else you pass item(0) to the regex function.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, perhaps I am making it too difficult for myself

Comment: Try `^(.+?)M(\d+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\s.*)?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 3 groups for the example data, you might make the pattern a bit more specific

```
^([^\W_]+)M(\d+)([^\W_]+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\W_]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars without an `_`
- `M` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `([^\W_]+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ word chars without an `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X6j5wj/1)

If you optionally want to match a whitespace char followed by optional chars:

```
^([^\W_]+)M(\d+)([^\W_]+)(?:\s.*)?$
```

Note that `\s` could also match a newline

Comment: If, say, one of the groups I get from this expression is called NutMaterial and actual value I get is "A2_LH" and I have a code that says  If NutMaterial = "A2" Or "Zn" Then. Would that be a correct code? Because it seems to still consider"A2_LH" as "A2"

Comment: @Eduards The pattern does not match an underscore, so `A2_LH` can not match. If you get that value somehow, you can either split on `_` and compare the first part, or use another pattern that matches that string and use the first group like `^([^\W_]+)_[^\W_]+$` https://regex101.com/r/BJdezC/1

Comment: Nah, I figured it out. It was because I put two criterias in a line with an "Or". So i Did tehm separately with IF and Elseif - and now it works. Thanks